# Dart: Make a calculation from a user input String including math operators

Tags: string, math, dart, flutter, double

i am new in Dart and Flutter. Is there an easy way to calculate an user input as a String like '3+5/8? Of course the result should be double-type. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: This is a pretty broad question - the best way to proceed might be to do some research by yourself (there's a lot of existing material, like [How to evaluate a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)), and come back to Stack Overflow if you get stuck after choosing which approach to take :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the link. Of course i have an idea to code this "manually". I was just curious, if something already exist in an easy way. For sure i will do more research in deeper way. And yes, i can comment then my conclusions here 

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for simple mathematical strings, you calculate them with the help of a package called

- [petitparser](https://pub.dev/packages/petitparser)

First install this package. Add it into your project and then implement this code.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:petitparser/petitparser.dart';

Parser buildParser() {
  final builder = ExpressionBuilder();
  builder.group()
    ..primitive((pattern('+-').optional() &
            digit().plus() &
            (char('.') & digit().plus()).optional() &
            (pattern('eE') & pattern('+-').optional() & digit().plus())
                .optional())
        .flatten('number expected')
        .trim()
        .map(num.tryParse))
    ..wrapper(
        char('(').trim(), char(')').trim(), (left, value, right) => value);
  builder.group()..prefix(char('-').trim(), (op, a) => -a);
  builder.group()..right(char('^').trim(), (a, op, b) => pow(a, b));
  builder.group()
    ..left(char('*').trim(), (a, op, b) => a * b)
    ..left(char('/').trim(), (a, op, b) => a / b);
  builder.group()
    ..left(char('+').trim(), (a, op, b) => a + b)
    ..left(char('-').trim(), (a, op, b) => a - b);
  return builder.build().end();
}

double calcString(String text) {
  final parser = buildParser();
  final input = text;
  final result = parser.parse(input);
  if (result.isSuccess)
    return result.value.toDouble();
  else
    return double.parse(text);
}
```

Now just call this function *calcString* and you will get the required answer. **Remember** it will only return the calculated value if the given string is **valid** else it will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a package that can do "expression evaluation". Searching on the pub site for ["expression"](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages?q=expression) yields a few results that look promising.

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/expressions
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/math_expressions

I don't have any direct experience with these packages so I can't recommend one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I will look at the links and go deeper in this topic now!

Answer (score 0):

I just programmed the Shunting-yard algorithm in Dart, problem solved =) 
Visit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: Hello, I know this post is old but I was wondering if you were able to share an example of this as I am stuck with this problem myself?